# How to return a HashMap having enum parameters of the method?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have method returnSpecificOrder(Type type) (like in code below) where Type is enum class , this method should return only Orders containing item.type = "Clothes" where Item is another class witch have variable public Type type;I try to return orders from hashMap but java says that can't resolve symbol , how I should change my method ?

```
public class Order {
    public long id;
    public LocalDate dateTime;
    public User user;
    public List<Item> items;

//set seters and geters  

    public HashMap<Long, Order>  createOrder() {
    Order myFirstOrder = new Order();
        myFirstOrder.setId(1);
        myFirstOrder.setDateTime(LocalDate.now());
        myFirstOrder.setUser(user);
        myFirstOrder.setItems(items);

    Order mySecondOrder = new Order();
        mySecondOrder.setId(2);
        mySecondOrder.setDateTime(LocalDate.now());
        mySecondOrder.setUser(user);
        mySecondOrder.setItems(item2);

    //hash map of orders
    HashMap<Long, Order> orders = new HashMap<>();
        orders.put(myFirstOrder.getId(), myFirstOrder);
        orders.put(mySecondOrder.getId(), mySecondOrder);
        return orders;
}

    //method that will return only Orders containing item.type = "Clothes"
    public static Map<Long, Order> returnSpecificOrder(Type type) {
        return orders.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(o -> o.getValue().getItems().stream().anyMatch(item -> item.getType() == Type.clothes))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
    }            }
```

Comment: Your prose and your code are both convoluted. I suggest you cut away the irrelevant, to focus your Question.

Comment: I cut away the irrelevant part, now it should be less convulted

Answer (score 1):

your filter should work.

The following is the working codes.

I refactored your Entity classes, and added comments where needed.

```
class Order {
    public long id;
    public List<Item> items;

    //convenient constructor.
    public Order(long id, Type... items) {
        this.id = id;
        this.items = Arrays.stream(items).map(Item::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}

class Item {
    Type type;

    public Item(Type type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}

enum Type {
    Clothes, NotClothes, Car, Bicycle, Shoes
}
```

Then added your filter method into main

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        

        //pre-populate with sample data
        Order o1 = new Order(1, Type.Bicycle, Type.Car, Type.Clothes);
        Order o2 = new Order(2, Type.NotClothes, Type.Bicycle);
        HashMap<Long, Order> orders = new HashMap<>();
        orders.put(1L, o1);
        orders.put(2L, o2);

        //method that will return only Orders containing item.type = "Clothes"
        Map<Long, Order> result = orders.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(o -> {
                    //I Split into two lines to make it less cluttered.
                    List<Item> list = o.getValue().items;
                    return list.stream().anyMatch(item  -> item.type == Type.Clothes);
                }).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

        //The answer shows that only 1 item is returned.
        System.out.println("result = " + result.size());
    }

}
```